# How to change default playback and recording device names in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, regedit

In Windows when a recording device plugged in, the device alias name becomes "Microphone", but I want it "M" for new devices. By default I want it like this:

[image]

Not like this:

[image]

Also the same thing is necessary for playback devices, I want them with default alias as "S" instead of "Speaker".

How can I change it for all new plugged devices. When I change it for a device, its alias changes, but I want to change it for newly plugged ones.

Perhaps it might be somewhere in regedit, but I can not find..

Answer (score 1):

You can listen the newly plugged devices and rename their names programatically.
I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

it's here ( for who's reading and looking for answer )

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture**

All play and record device are there

You can rename key, that will change the peripheral name instantly without reboot